# Calculating vertices of a rotated rectangle

Tags: c++, math, matrix, trigonometry, rectangles

I am trying to calculate the vertices of a rotated rectangle (2D).

It's easy enough if the rectangle has not been rotated, I figured that part out.

If the rectangle has been rotated, I thought of two possible ways to calculate the vertices.

1. Figure out how to transform the vertices from local/object/model space (the ones I figured out below) to world space. I honestly have no clue, and if it is the best way then I feel like I would learn a lot from it if I could figure it out.
2. Use trig to somehow figure out where the endpoints of the rectangle are relative to the position of the rectangle in world space. This has been the way I have been trying to do up until now, I just haven't figured out how.

Here's the function that calculates the vertices thus far, thanks for any help

```
void Rect::calculateVertices()
{
    if(m_orientation == 0) // if no rotation
    {
        setVertices(
        &Vertex( (m_position.x - (m_width / 2) * m_scaleX), (m_position.y + (m_height / 2) * m_scaleY), m_position.z), 
        &Vertex( (m_position.x + (m_width / 2) * m_scaleX), (m_position.y + (m_height / 2) * m_scaleY), m_position.z),
        &Vertex( (m_position.x + (m_width / 2) * m_scaleX), (m_position.y - (m_height / 2) * m_scaleY), m_position.z),
        &Vertex( (m_position.x - (m_width / 2) * m_scaleX), (m_position.y - (m_height / 2) * m_scaleY), m_position.z) );
    }
    else
    {
        // if the rectangle has been rotated..
    }

    //GLfloat theta = RAD_TO_DEG( atan( ((m_width/2) * m_scaleX) / ((m_height / 2) * m_scaleY) ) );
    //LOG->writeLn(&theta);

}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would just transform each point, applying the same rotation matrix to each one.  If it's a 2D planar rotation, it would look like this:

```
x' = x*cos(t) - y*sin(t)
y' = x*sin(t) + y*cos(t)
```

where (x, y) are the original points, (x', y') are the rotated coordinates, and t is the angle measured in radians from the x-axis.  The rotation is counter-clockwise as written.

My recommendation would be to do it out on paper once.  Draw a rectangle, calculate the new coordinates, and redraw the rectangle to satisfy yourself that it's correct before you code.  Then use this example as a unit test to ensure that you coded it properly.

Comment: +1 - I tend to prefer rotating back and then doing any work, makes life simpler.

Comment: This way you can get by with only doing 2 trig operations (if you store the results of `cos(t)` and `sin(t)` before computing any rotated vertices).

Comment: How would this formula be to rotate clockwise?

Comment: Forget my question. Just make the angle negative :)

Comment: @duffymo Do you have a source for this transform? Works well, just wanna understand.

Comment: Any book on linear algebra or 2D vectors will have it.  Is Google not installed on your machine?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Answer (score 2):

I think you were on the right track using `atan()` to return an angle.  However you want to pass `height` divided by `width` instead of the other way around.  That will give you the default (unrotated) angle to the upper-right vertex of the rectangle.  You should be able to do the rest like this:

```
// Get the original/default vertex angles
GLfloat vertex1_theta = RAD_TO_DEG( atan(
            (m_height/2 * m_scaleY)
            / (m_width/2 * m_scaleX) ) );
GLfloat vertex2_theta = -vertex1_theta; // lower right vertex
GLfloat vertex3_theta = vertex1_theta - 180; // lower left vertex
GLfloat vertex4_theta = 180 - vertex1_theta; // upper left vertex

// Now get the rotated vertex angles
vertex1_theta += rotation_angle;
vertex2_theta += rotation_angle;
vertex3_theta += rotation_angle;
vertex4_theta += rotation_angle;

//Calculate the distance from the center (same for each vertex)
GLfloat r = sqrt(pow(m_width/2*m_scaleX, 2) + pow(m_height/2*m_scaleY, 2));

/* Calculate each vertex (I'm not familiar with OpenGL, DEG_TO_RAD
 * might be a constant instead of a macro)
 */
vertexN_x = m_position.x + cos(DEG_TO_RAD(vertexN_theta)) * r;
vertexN_y = m_position.y + sin(DEG_TO_RAD(vertexN_theta)) * r;

// Now you would draw the rectangle, proceeding from vertex1 to vertex4.
```

Obviously more longwinded than necessary, for the sake of clarity.  Of course, duffymo's solution using a transformation matrix is probably more elegant and efficient :)

**EDIT**:  Now my code should actually work.  I changed `(width / height)` to `(height / width)` and used a constant radius from the center of the rectangle to calculate the vertices.  Working Python (turtle) code at http://pastebin.com/f1c76308c

Comment: DEG_TO_RAD is a macro I wrote.